# how to segregate Chat history messages in android without using local storage? I am using service to get history

Tags: android

How to load chat history message in android without using local storage? My  doubt is, I am getting chat history messages from a service and I am loading it to a list. But if any other person chat at that time I am getting that message in that list itself, how to segregate that message from other person chat? Like how they have done in Google talk.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give you an appropriate answer without further details:
1) How is the service passing data to your UI? (Cursor, Object Oriented Domain Model)
2) From where are those Chat Messages coming? If it is a online service, is offline caching really no option?

Code snippets are also helping to clarify the situation.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I am using GCM push notification, i am saving the chat messages in cloud from there i am getting chat history.. just like list

Answer (score 0):

Its some complex, see
when you opening chat screen, just save userId(id of that friend with which you are chating) in prefrences, so when you receive new message in **onMessage() method of GCMIntentService** class then compare userId(coming with message) with userId(you saved in preferences), if id matched you do not need to call generate notification method, just simply show message in your chat list, if id does not matched, then call to generate notification method(as currently happening), and does not put message in chat list.

Comment: i am using GCM for chat application... i can able to chat one to one when they are online  but i am unable to differentiate who is sending chat message. for Instance: if a is chatting with b if c sends chat it will be upload in list. im using local broad cast message to append that message to list view.